# Сериализация XML документа

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Необходимо сериализовать документ в качестве теста. Файл готовый, по нему сгенерированы классы. Почему студия каждый тег создало в виде класса и как это все правильно сериализовать? Пока выходит ошибка в рантайме.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<AapSelector xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<Sections>
   <Section>
     <Type>FAP</Type>
   </Section>
 </Sections>
</AapSelector>
```

Класс:

```
[Serializable]
public partial class AapSelector
{
    public AapSelectorSections Sections { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public partial class AapSelectorSections
{
   public AapSelectorSectionsSection Section { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public partial class AapSelectorSectionsSection
{

     public string Type { get; set; }
}

class Program
{

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var A = new AapSelector();

    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(A.GetType());

    serializer.Serialize(Console.Out, serializer);
    Console.WriteLine();

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

}

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Банальная опечатка, посмотрите что вы пытаетесь сериализовать: `serializer.Serialize(Console.Out, A);`

Comment: попробуйте еще задать тип!

Comment: О, благодарю! Но у меня вопрос, а почему три класса генерируется? И как мне это сериализовать в вышеуказанный документ?

Comment: `var A = new AapSelector();
        A.Sections = new AapSelectorSections();
        A.Sections.Section = new AapSelectorSectionsSection();
        A.Sections.Section.Type = "APP";` Можно ли сделать так, что бы модель была в одном классе?

Comment: Напишите отдельным вопросом какую вы хотите иметь модель и во что она должна сериализоваться

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак, попробую сам ответить на свой вопрос. Ибо потанцевав с бубном, решил проблему. В том числе благодаря полученным здесь ответам! Названия тегов изменены на более подходящие в моем случае.
Модель

```
public class Cap
{
    [Serializable]
    public class PanelSelector
    {
        [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "Section")]
        public List<PanelSelectorSection> Sections { get; set; }
        public PanelSelector()
        {
            Sections = new List<PanelSelectorSection>();
        }
    }

    public class PanelSelectorSection
    {
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Main:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var panelSelector = new Cap.PanelSelector();
    panelSelector.Sections.Add(new Cap.PanelSelectorSection());
    panelSelector.Sections[0].Type = "AAAA";

    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Cap.PanelSelector));
    serializer.Serialize(Console.Out, panelSelector);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Вывод:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну как бы классов у вас меньше не стало из-за того что вы их сделали вложенными

Answer (score 1):

Как уже ответили в комментариях, ошибка устраняется следующим образом:

```
serializer.Serialize(Console.Out, A);
```

А, вывести сформированный XML в файл можно так:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("data.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
    serializer.Serialize(fs, A);
}
```